Content refresh and login integration issues with cookies in ReactNative iOS WebView
I am displaying a website through WebView in a React Native app. The website includes "recommended items" and "checked items" content, which works fine on Android but does not refresh on iOS when navigating to the WebView through footer tabs.
However, if I set sharedCookiesEnabled and thirdPartyCookiesEnabled to false, the content refreshes correctly, but the login integration between the WebView and the app breaks.
Is there a way to solve this issue and still maintain the login integration?
